# what arguments for inline C functions in varnish

Tags: vcl, varnish, cache-invalidation

I found in varnish book that varnish 3 purge functionality could be somehow achieved in varnish 2.1 by

> `C{ VRT_Nuke(...); }C`

signature of VTR_Nuke seems to be

> `int VRT_nuke(struct sess *sp, const char *str, ...)`

in my default.vcl I want to write something like:

```
sub vcl_hit {
    C{ VRT_Nuke(...); }C
    error 200 "Purged";
}
```

what arguments should I give the VRT_Nuke function?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Upgrade to 3.0 and avoid yourself some pain.